# ion-nav-view with name attribute not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I have a tab layout like such

```
<ion-view id="viewTickets" class=" ">
<ion-nav-bar class = "bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-back-button class = "button-clear" ng-click = "">
      <i class = "icon ion-arrow-left-c"></i>
    </ion-nav-back-button>
    <ion-nav-title ng-click="">
        Tickets
    </ion-nav-title>
</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-positive">
    <ion-tab title="Personal">
            <ion-nav-view name="viewtickets-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="All">
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

And I see the two tab options, then in my app.js .config I have

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider

.state('viewtickets', {
    url: '/viewtickets',
    templateUrl: 'templates/viewtickets.html',
    controller: 'ViewTicketsCtrl'
  })
  .state('viewtickets.viewticketstab', {
        url: '/viewticketstab',
        views: {
            'viewtickets-tab': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/viewticketstab.html',
            }
        }
  })
```

But I dont see the `templates/viewticketstab.html'` loaded when I am on the Personal tab, it is just empty below, here is the viewticketstab.html

```
<ion-view title="tickets tab">
     <ion-content class="padding">
        <h1>Tab 1</h1>

     </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Why is viewticketstab.html being put in the Personal Tab?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
.state('viewtickets', {
    url: '/viewtickets',
    templateUrl: 'templates/viewtickets.html',
    controller: 'ViewTicketsCtrl'
  })
  .state('viewtickets.viewticketstab', {
        url: '/viewticketstab',
        views: {
            'viewtickets-tab': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/viewticketstab.html',
            }
        }
  })
```

Try this out:

```
.state('viewtickets', {
    url: '/viewtickets',
    templateUrl: 'templates/viewtickets.html',
    controller: 'ViewTicketsCtrl',
    views: {
            'viewtickets-tab': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/viewticketstab.html',
            }
        }
  })
```